# Not Unit Testing external code

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

It is said that if a class uses an **external** resource then that **external resource** call is not be tested. So, if there is **class** like below;

```
public interface IVideo
{
string VideoName();        
}

public class Video : IVideo
{
    public string VideoName()
    {
         var obj = new VideoReader("videoPath.avi").GetName();

         ////some other code
    }
}
```

In order to unit test, we would create a fake class which would inherit from IVideo and implement like below,

```
public string VideoName()
        {
            return "";
        }
```

My question is why don't we test **actual code** which calls **actual Video class** object?

Answer (score 1):

You should test the actual `Video` class. What you should do is injecting the instance of `VideoReader` into `Video` instead of newing it up inside of your class. E.g.

```
class Video
{
    private VideoReader videoReader;
    public Video(VideoReader videoReader)
    {
        this.videoReader = videoReader;
    }
    public string VideoName()
    {
        videoReader.GetName();

        ////some other code
    }
}

var videoReader = new VideoReader("videoPath.avi");
var video = new Video(videoReader);
string name = video.VideoName();
```

In your test you pass a mocked `VideoReader` instead of the real thing.